# What widget(s) can be used for liquid and fixed columns with column span in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to do the following:

```
Apple   | 2 kg | button 1 | button 2 |
Orange  | 1 kg |         info        |
Orange  | 2 kg |         info        |
Pear    |              ?             |
...
```

First column with names must be liquid, and other three column must be fixed size. I planned to use table, but as I found out colspan in tables is [not supported currently](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21594). Could anyone say what widget(s) I should use for such a task?

Comment: i think this could be achieved with only row and column.